# POSTGRESQL The record are not not inserted?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am stuck at my query, whenever I want to insert the record. I've already check it on lastDate variable and total variable sum from other table but still couldn't solve it with it.

**Query**

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
   indexing INTEGER;
   lastIndex INTEGER;
   total_temp int8;
   dateTime timestamp;
   lastDate timestamp;
   isExists integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT outcome_id, created_at INTO lastIndex, dateTime FROM public.outcomes_details 
    ORDER BY outcome_id DESC LIMIT 1;

    indexing := 1;

    WHILE indexing <= lastIndex
    LOOP
        SELECT created_at INTO lastDate FROM public.outcomes_details where outcome_id = indexing 
        ORDER BY outcome_id DESC LIMIT 1;
        SELECT SUM(total) INTO total_temp FROM public.outcomes_details 
        WHERE outcome_id = indexing;
   
        select  outcome_id into isExists from public.outcomes where outcome_id = indexing order by outcome_id  
       desc limit 1;
       SELECT TO_CHAR(lastDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') into lastDate;
  
       RAISE NOTICE 'Index: %, Total: %, Exists: %, LastDate: %', indexing, total_temp, isExists, lastDate;
    
       IF lastIndex IS NULL then
          INSERT INTO public.outcomes
          (outcome_date, total)
          VALUES (lastDate, total_temp);
       else
          UPDATE public.outcomes
          SET total = total_temp
          WHERE outcome_id = indexing;
       end if;

    
      indexing := indexing + 1;
    END LOOP;
 perform * from public.outcomes;
END $$;
```

then when i check it to the outcomes here is the result

[image]

Even tough when i check it on output there are the data existed

[image]

What I want is I want to create a record on outcomes table that 3 data are existsed,
How to solve this?

Comment: Please show all the input data, then the command that you're executing, then all the actual output data, then tell us what the desired outcome is.

Comment: How can lastIndex ever be NULL in that loop?  Maybe you meant to test something else.

Comment: 1) **DO NOT use images for textual data**. Copy and paste as text into you question. 2) In your output you circle rows that have `Exists: <NULL>`. In your code you have `RAISE NOTICE 'Index: %, Total: %, Exists: %, LastDate: %', indexing, total_temp, isExists, lastDate;` where `Exists: %,` matches up with `isExists`. Your test though is ;`IF lastIndex IS NULL then ...`. As @jjanes mentioned, it looks like you are testing the wrong value.